# Add an 'active' class to slideshow navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I have created a slideshow that fades images in and out on an interval with jQuery. I created a navigation area at the bottom that, when you click on a square, it displays that slide. Two things I need assistance on.

When you click on a navigation square, the timing is off until it goes to the next natural slide.

I need the current slide's square to be a different color. I have been trying to add a class to the square with the matching ID, but it doesn't add a class.

```
    $("#slideshow1 > div:gt(0)").hide();

var newvar = setInterval(function() { 
    var currentslide = $('.current').attr('id');
    $('#slideshow1 > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .addClass('current')
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .removeClass('current')
    .appendTo('#slideshow1');
    $('.slider-nav').removeClass('active');
    $('.slider-nav[data-number=' + currentslide + ']').addClass('active');
},  5000);

$(".slider-nav").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentID = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#slideshow1 > div:first').fadeOut(1000);
    $('div'+currentID).fadeIn(1000).nextAll("div.slide").addBack().prependTo("#slideshow1");
    $('.slider-nav').removeClass('active');
    $('.slider-nav[data-number=' + currentID + ']').addClass('active');
    clearInterval(newvar);
    newvar = setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow1 > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .addClass('current')
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .removeClass('current')
        .appendTo('#slideshow1');
        $('.slider-nav').removeClass('active');
        $('.slider-nav[data-number=' + currentID + ']').addClass('active');
    },  5000);
});
```

The website where this slideshow is: http://saratoga.mspaceap.com/

Comment: Your navigation elements and slides shouldn't have identical IDs. IDs should always be unique. I can see you're trying to work around this using `.attr('id')`, but it's still bad practice. Use a common `data-` attribute or an id like `nav1` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$('.slider-nav[id=' + currentID + ']').addClass('active');
```

Because `currentID` is a string like `#1`, since you set it three lines earlier to be:

```
var currentID = $(this).attr('href');
```

To fix, change your code to:

```
$('.slider-nav[id=' + currentID.substr(1) + ']').addClass('active')
    .siblings().removeClass('active'); // don't forget to do this
```

---

That said: Your navigation elements and slides shouldn't have identical IDs. IDs should always be unique. I can see you're working around this using `.attr('id')`, but it's still bad practice. Use a common `data-` attribute or an id like `nav1` instead.

Comment: So I have changed the nav id to a data-number. How do I go about adding and removing the class where the data-number equals the current slide id?

Comment: Use code similar to what you have now, but select `.slidernav[data-id='+currentID+']` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assign setInterval to a variable like this:

```
$("#slideshow1 > div:gt(0)").hide();

var interval = setInterval(function() { 
    var currentslide = $('.current').attr('id');

    $('#slideshow1 > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .addClass('current')
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .removeClass('current')
        .appendTo('#slideshow1');
    },  5000);
}
```

Then make use of `clearInterval` in your click handler like this:

```
$(".slider-nav").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentID = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#slideshow1 > div:first').fadeOut(1000);
    $('div'+currentID).fadeIn(1000).nextAll("div.slide").addBack().prependTo("#slideshow1");
    $('.slider-nav[id=' + currentID + ']').addClass('active');
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

That way your interval will be reset on click.